# Is is possible to write a simple android runtime in c++ in universal windows platform to wrap a apk?

Tags: android, android-emulator, uwp

So akp can run in windows 10 mobile. It does not need to use the same background task mechanism, just reopen it each time, assume that will make it easier to implement.

Comment: Android apps cannot run on w10 mobile. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter I was thinking, since simple emulator for old game consoles can be emulated and thus run games. Is it possible to write a android emulator (or just simply replica the runtime) in c++ to enable apk in a wrapper-like environment in w10m. Microsoft did it with built-in android subsystem but it got removed. Is it possible to write an app for that purpose?